# Standard web communication technologies?

Tags: web, websocket, xmlhttprequest, communication

I'm not even sure how to phrase this question in a specific way, but I want to know if there are any standard methods of web communication besides the following that I know of...

1. XMLHttpRequest (XHR)
2. WebSockets

May be someone can help me frame my question to use the right words, because "standard web communication technologies" sounds kinda of broad.

Comment: It's extremely broad.  `"The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from." - Andrew S. Tanenbaum`  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

1. Regular HTTP (including JSONP)
2. XMLHttpRequest (XHR)
3. WebSockets
4. Server Sent Events

Everything else are variations or combinations of these techniques.